# Number of equations and variables in a Linear Programming problem

Tags: linear-programming

Why in every Linear Programming problem in standard form it's assumed that $m\leq n$ (where m are the rows and n the columns of the A matrix) ?
Thanks

Comment: if m> n then how will you solve for the extra (m-n) variables then you can only obtain the solution in form of the left variables

Comment: The missing information in your question is that the "m" equations have to be **independent** . If this is the case the necceassry condition that the equation system has a solution is $m\leq n$ If they are  independent and $m>n$ no solution exists.

Comment: @James You probably  mean $m<n$.

Answer (score 1):

If $m>n$, it means there are redundancy in the constraints of which you can reduce the number of linear equations, hence it suffices to only focus on the case where $m \le n$.

Answer (score 0):

Each equality constraint may be used to eliminate one variable, so the standard problem consists only of inequality constraints. Each has a slack or surplus variable added to convert it to an equality, so the number of variables n always exceeds the number of constraints m.